# Java: Synchronizing clearing of a map while another thread could be writing into it

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a code like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
    private Set<String> keys;
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Something> map;

    public void startTask()
    {
        future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new SomeTask(), ...);
    }

    public void stopTask()
    {
        future.cancel(true);
        map.clear();
    }

    private class SomeTask implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for (String key : keys)
            {
                if (Thread.interrupted())
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Getting value...

                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that `map` is empty when `stopTask` exits.
I am thinking about making the method wait until the task has exited by using some synchronizer, however, I'm not sure which one would work better. There's also may be another, better way to do what I need.

The task has only one instance and can be rescheduled later after cancellation, if it matters.

Comment: How about `future.get()`?

Comment: I'm not really sure how it works with recurring tasks... Oh, I forgot to mention that in the question, sorry.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that nothing can access `map` after `clear()` has been called?

Comment: What if I call `future.cancel(true)` while the task is running and it is right before `map.put(key, value);`?

Comment: I suggest you try it out. You'll probably need to catch and ignore `CancellationException`.

Comment: Tried using `future.get()`. After `future.cancel(true)` it just throws `CancellationException` and doesn't wait for the task to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I've basically two answers to your question:

Whenever you call `future.cancel(true)` or `executor.shutdownNow()`it calls `interrupt()` either for the one task or for all threads in the thread pool. The `interrupt()` is ignored by any Java method except the ones that can throw `InterruptedException`, like e.g. `Thread.sleep()`. In your case, the code to "get value" and put that value into the map will not be interrupted. The only possible point of interruption is where you've code it - or, if any method you call to get the value might throw `InterruptedException`.

But, do you really just want to stop the one task, not the scheduler itself? I would prefer to stop scheduling instead of just canceling on task. Here's a code snippet I use to stop any kind of thread pool and wait till all tasks have finished:

```
public void stopTask()
{
    executor.shutdownNow(); // Stops submitting new tasks and sends interrupt to running tasks

    // Wait for tasks to complete
    while(!executor.isTerminated()) try {
        executor.awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if(!executor.isTerminated())
            System.out.println("Still waiting for scheduled tasks to finish");
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    map.clear();
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

The `shutdownNow()` ensures, that the current running task gets `interrupt()`called.